# Acquiring information about binary from decimal

Tags: c

Suppose that an instruction `aw` is code 010 defined by a 32 bit structure as follows:

```
bits 31-25  unused (all 0s)
bits 24-22: code
bits 21-19: argument 1
bits 18-16: argument 2
bits 15-0:  offset (a 16-bit, 2's complement number with a range of -32768 to 32767)
```

Given the number 8454151, how can I determine if the code is `aw`?

I tried to shift the number 22 bits, like 8454151 >> 22, but I keep getting 0.  Any ideas on how I can obtain the bit information for the code (to check whether it's `aw` or something else)?

Answer (score 2):

If you just have to verify if an instruction is of a certain operation, the code needing the least cycles would be as follows:

```
const uint32_t mask = 7 << 22;    // Shift 3 set bits by 22 in order to build 
                                  // a mask where bits 22-24 are set.
const uint32_t inst_aw = 2 << 22; // Shift the opcode by 22 to build a comparable value

uint32_t instruction = ...;       // Your instruction word

if ((instruction & mask) == inst_aw) {
  // Do your thing
}
```

Anyway if you have to build something like an "instruction decoder" or "interpreter", I'd recommend using a lookup table with instruction names (or function pointers) indexed by the instruction code:

```
/*! \brief Instruction names lookup table. Make sure it has always 8 entries 
           in order to avoid access beyond the array limits */
const char *instruction_names[] = {
  /* 000 */ "Unknown instruction 000",
  /* 001 */ "Unknown instruction 001",
  /* 010 */ "AW",
  ...
  /* 111 */ "Unknown instruction 111"
};


uint32_t instruction = ...;
unsigned int opcode = (instruction >> 22) & 0x07; // Retrieving the opcode by shifting right 22 
                                                  // times and mask out all bit except the last 3

printf("Instruction is: %s", instruction_names[opcode]);
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit shift should work. Be sure to check the data types. You can also "and" the number with 0x01C000 and then compare.

Comment: I'd prefer to encode this magic number having a constant or define building it from understandable pieces (like `7 << 22` or `2 << 22`) to make it more readable for other people.

Comment: Make sure you're using a 4-byte integer when you do the shift.